# Is there a way to display tweets obtained from API other than using custom css and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, twitter

I have finally got the API working successfully allowing me to query the Twitter API and obtaining tweets. How does one display these tweets? Do I have to use custom css and html or is there an easier way to embed the twitter timeline without using the widget?

Comment: Have you found a method that does so, if yes why are you asking, if not why should we be able to find sth?

Comment: Twitter does have embedded timelines which come with twitter styling : https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Comment: Twitter embedded timelines dont allow me to dynamically enter a search term depending on my webpage user.

Answer (score 1):

[OEmbed](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) is your friend :-)

Let's say you saw my excellent Tweet - https://twitter.com/edent/status/860905721646338048

To convert it to HTML, call this URL:

https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fedent%2Fstatus%2F860905721646338048

You'll get back some JSON.  Part of that response will be a HTML representation of the Tweet.

```
    "html": "\u003Cblockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\"\u003E\u003Cp lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\"\u003ELet&#39;s get this (pizza) party started! \u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/t.co\/W2vhWX6wZz\"\u003Epic.twitter.com\/W2vhWX6wZz\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E&mdash; ꧁Terence Eden꧂ ⏻ (@edent) \u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/twitter.com\/edent\/status\/860905721646338048\"\u003EMay 6, 2017\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/blockquote\u003E\n\u003Cscript async src=\"\/\/platform.twitter.com\/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E",
```

Place that HTML on your website, and it will display without you needing to do anything else.

That API call does not require authentication. There are a range of options available - see the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed

Comment: How would I call that URL though? Thanks for the help though, this seems to be what I've been searching for. @Terence

Comment: What programming language are you using? You can open that URL in your browser if you like.

Comment: @TerenceEden Embed is not working for me on IE 11. So I am assuming API is only way. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of libraries on https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries#javascript-node-js

Comment: Thanks for the advice but how will the libraries help me? I dont want to access more data, I just want to display the tweets on my webpage in a similar manner that twitter does. @Stephan Stanisic